# Rails constraint on route that contains dynamic segment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following two routes in my Rails app:

```
match '/users/:username' => 'users#show', :via => :get, :as => :user
match '/users(/:filter)' => 'users#index', :via => :get, :as => :users
```

This is so that I can have routes like:

`/users/cameron`
`/users/popular`

Where the first is a user, and the second is a filter.

However the routing in Rails will always hit the first route, because it doesn't know the difference between `:username` and `:filter`.

For posts I avoid this problem by doing:

```
match '/posts/:id' => 'posts#show', :via => :get, :as => :post, :id => /[0-9]/
```

But this only works because posts are always integers. For example: `/posts/21`

How can I apply a constraint to my user routes so that they don't trip over each other and without having to add a prefix to either of them.

Comment: why not having a query string on the url instead for the filtering? (i.e. `users?filter=popular`)

Comment: @MarioPérez Short answer is... I don't want to :)

Comment: Perhaps then using some constraint that checks whether the string is a username or not http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints so you could pick the proper route. But querying the database there doesn't seems right for the performance. If it's your only option ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @MarioPérez See my updated post for what I have tried. Thanks.

Comment: did it work? Also `lambda { |request| User.exists?(username: request.params[:username]) }` may be faster

Comment: @MarioPérez Yes it works. Why would your version be faster? (I'm new to Ruby and Rails).

Comment: I think using your version is loading all the records into memory and using a method from the Array class. With my version I'm just querying the database for the thing I need which I believe will be much faster. You could find some info in this article: http://www.webascender.com/Blog/ID/553/Rails-Tips-for-Speeding-up-ActiveRecord-Queries

And again I would encourage to go the way I talked about it before. It will follow REST and much less complicated code :)

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this approach (based on the link provided by @Mario

`match '/users/:username' => 'users#show', :via => :get, :as => :user, :constraints => lambda { |request| User.usernames.include?(request.params[:username]) }`

and in my User model:

```
def self.usernames
  User.pluck(:username)
end
```